# Why does my iPad send me immediately to the App Store instead of Safari?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I tapped on Safari and suddenly it sent me to the App Store. I tried going back to Safari but it just kept going to the App Store. It just wants me to buy random apps that I don't want.

Comment: what does it want from you in the store ?

Comment: Safari was likely last opened to a page that had an iTunes link in it, forwarding you to the App store (similar to ads that people accidentally click on in Games). Try fully closing out the Safari session by double-clicking on the Home button on your iPad, then swipe Safari up from the Multitasker. Then, make sure the session won't reload by going to Settings -> Safari -> Clear website data and history. It will blow your Safari history away but should clear whatever site it has open as well. Note, bookmarks won't be affected by that process :)

Comment: On which iOS version ?

Comment: @smoooosher Can you add this as an answer below?

Comment: @patrix Done :)

Comment: iOS 8 to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

Safari was likely last opened to a page that had an iTunes link in it, forwarding you to the App store (similar to ads that people accidentally click on in Games). Try fully closing out the Safari session by double-clicking on the Home button on your iPad, then swipe Safari up from the Multitasker. Then, make sure the session won't reload by going to Settings -> Safari -> Clear website data and history. It will blow your Safari history away but should clear whatever site it has open as well. Note, bookmarks won't be affected by that process :)

Or try to follow a link from Mail, Twitter etc (whatever opens in Safari), then open the "all tabs" view in Safari and close the 'tab' with the auto-forwarding.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe a Settings link...